# How do I invoke Multiple Startup Projects when running a unit tests in Debug Mode

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, resharper

This seems like a simple thing to do but I can't seem to find any info anywhere!  I've got a solution that has a service that we run in 'Console Mode' when debugging. I want it to be started and 'attached' when I run my unit test from Visual Studio.

I'm using Resharper as the unit test runner.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to mock the service in your test and then test the service separately?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, BUT
We faced a similar problem recently and eventually settled on a solution using `AppDomain`

As your solution is already running as a Console project it would be little work to make it boot in a new AppDomain. Furthermore, you could run Assertions on this project as well as part of unit testing. (if required)

Consider the following static class `Sandbox`  which you can use to boot multiple app domains.
The Execute method requires a Type which is-a `SandboxAction`. (class definition also included below)

You would first *extend* this class and provide any bootup actions for running your console project.

```
public class ConsoleRunnerProjectSandbox : SandboxAction
{
  protected override void OnRun()
    {
         Bootstrapper.Start(); //this code will be run on the newly create app domain
    }

}
```

Now to get your app domain running you simply call

```
Sandbox.Execute<ConsoleRunnerProjectSandbox>("AppDomainName", configFile)
```

Note you can pass this call a config file so you can bootup your project *in the same fashion as if you were running it via the console*

Any more questions please ask.

```
public static class Sandbox
{
    private static readonly List<Tuple<AppDomain, SandboxAction>> _sandboxes = new List<Tuple<AppDomain, SandboxAction>>();

    public static T Execute<T>(string friendlyName, string configFile, params object[] args)
        where T : SandboxAction
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Sandboxing {0}: {1}", typeof (T).Name, configFile));

        AppDomain sandbox = CreateDomain(friendlyName, configFile);

        var objectHandle = sandbox.CreateInstance(typeof(T).Assembly.FullName, typeof(T).FullName, true, BindingFlags.Default, null, args, null, null, null);

        T sandBoxAction = objectHandle.Unwrap() as T;

        sandBoxAction.Run();


        Tuple<AppDomain, SandboxAction> box = new Tuple<AppDomain, SandboxAction>(sandbox, sandBoxAction);
        _sandboxes.Add(box);

        return sandBoxAction;
    }

    private static AppDomain CreateDomain(string name, string customConfigFile)
    {
        FileInfo info = customConfigFile != null ? new FileInfo(customConfigFile) : null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customConfigFile) && !info.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("customConfigFile not found using " + customConfigFile + " at " + info.FullName);

        var appsetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        //appsetup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Sandbox).Assembly.Location);
        appsetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
        if (customConfigFile==null)
            customConfigFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        appsetup.ConfigurationFile = customConfigFile;

        var sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            name,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
            appsetup);
        return sandbox;
    }

    public static void DestroyAppDomainForSandbox(SandboxAction action)
    {
        foreach(var tuple in _sandboxes)
        {
            if(tuple.Second == action)
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(tuple.First);
                Console.WriteLine("Unloaded sandbox ");
                _sandboxes.Remove(tuple);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


 [Serializable]
public abstract class SandboxAction : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        string name = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        Log.Info("Executing {0} in AppDomain:{1} thread:{2}", name, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        try
        {
            OnRun();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Exception in app domain {0}", name);
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnRun();

    public virtual void Stop()
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting.. so instead of starting the app separately in a console, start it in the test Initialisation in a separate AppDomain so will it be started with the debugger attached? Some code would be nice.

Comment: I'll add some code to my original post to get the markup. one sec

Comment: and yes, if you start it in the test initialization and you are debugging your tests then you are also debugging your console project.

Comment: cheers for the update, i'm just looking at the code; quick questions.. What's bootstrapper?

Comment: Bootstrapper is your class where all your startup code goes. When you create a Console project the entry point goes into Program.cs (from memory) so if you prefer you can simply call into that class.