# Run another project in the same solution while debugging unit test project in visual studio (2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a unit test project that needs a WebApi project to be run for passing some data to the main class library project in the same solution. for this purpose, I open another instance of visual studio and run this service on it and debug unit test in another instance.

Is there any solution to run depended projects while debugging or running unit tests in the same instance of visual studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoke Multiple Startup Projects when running a unit tests in Debug Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993806/how-do-i-invoke-multiple-startup-projects-when-running-a-unit-tests-in-debug-mod)